# How can I perform one-hot encoding on multiple categorical values (with unique values between 20 to 400) at once?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I have a file "Person_details.csv" which has total 507 columns (variables/features) and 50k rows. I have 7 categorical variables (['FirstRace','Languages', 'Ethnicity', 'City', 'Country', 'Month','Field'] and 500 numerical variables (eg: ['Person_ID','age', 'salary', 'experience', 'height', etc..]). These 7 categorical variables (['FirstRace','Languages', 'Ethnicity', 'City', 'Country', 'Month','Field']) have 20 to 400 unique values which will increase the feature space and hence I am choosing top 10 unique values while performing one-hot encoding with the following code. The code works fine but I am performing one hot encoding on each of the 7 categorical variable separately and saving them in a different file and then concatenating them back with the main file( Person_details.csv). Is there a way where I can perform encoding on all 7 variables at once and store them in a single file? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Code to perform one-hot encoding :

```
import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv("Person_details.csv", usecols= ['FirstRace','Languages', 'Ethnicity', 'City', 'Country', 'Month', 'Field'])
    for x in df.columns:
        #printing unique values
        print(x ,':', len(new_df[x].unique()))
    
    counts = df['FirstRace'].value_counts().sum()
    
    top_10_labels = [y for y in df.FirstRace.value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).head(10).index]
    df=pd.get_dummies(df['FirstRace']).sample(10)
    
    
    
    def top_x(df2,variable,top_x_labels):
        for label in top_x_labels:
            df2[variable+'_'+label] = np.where(data[variable]==label,1,0)
    data = pd.read_csv("Person_details.csv",usecols = ['Person_ID','FirstRace'])
    top_x(data,'FirstRace',top_10_labels)
    data.to_csv(r'First_race.csv', index=False)
```

In the above code every time I replace the categorical variable and perform one-hot encoding choose top 10 unique values and save them in a separate .csv file. Example: I replace 'FirstRace' with 'Languages' then with  'Ethnicity' etc.. starting from the line "counts = df['FirstRace'].value_counts().sum()" till last line I replace the column name every time and save the top 10 unique values of each categorical variable in different file.

Comment: I am still not able to figure out. Just to make this question simple. I want to perform one-hot encoding on 7 categorical variables, choose top 10 unique values and save the one hot encoded top 10 columns in the file. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to perform one hot encoding on multiple variables at once but I am not able to figure out how to add the name of the unique values as column name. It shows numbers along with the initial variable name.

Example:
For Languages variable I want the one hot encoded column name as Languages_English, Languages_Spanish,...Languages_Italian (top 10 values). But I am getting Languages_1, Languages_2,..., Languages_10. How can I get the names right.

This is the code I am using

```
data = pd.read_csv("Categorical_data.csv")
for column_name in data.columns:
    
    top_10 = data[column_name].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).head(10).index

    for number, value in enumerate(top_10):
        data[column_name + '_' + str(number)] = np.where(data[column_name].index==value, 1, 0)
```